# Is there in Javascript a way to determine that the error was SQLError?

Tags: javascript, sqlite

Is there in Javascript a way to determine that the error was SQLError? Example:

```
mydb.query()    // method returns Promise. It can throw SQLError by SQLite
    .catch(function(e){
        // some code to determine error type
    });
```

Comment: `e instanceof SQLError`? what module do you use to communicate with db?

Comment: @slavik I use standard browser database methods, wrapped in Promises by me.
Code `if(e instanceof SQLError)` throws `ReferenceError: SQLError is not defined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you search the spec https://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/ for "SQLError", you'll notice:

- In WebSQL, the error callbacks are *always* called with a SQLError.
- SQLError's are *only* used for error callbacks.
- SQLError is not a subclass of Error.

Also, promises should be rejected with an Error instance (see, for example, http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/warning-explanations.html#warning-a-promise-was-rejected-with-a-non-error).

Thus to reject a promise with a SQLError, you should convert it to an Error.  (If you want, you can make your own subclass of Error so that you can easily identify SQL errors with `instanceof`).

This is easy to do because at the point where WebSQL calls your error callback, you know you have SQLError object with `code` and `message` fields.

Answer (score 0):

try this one :

```
try{abc();}
catch(e){var err = e ; console.log(err.message);}
```

Comment: Your code returns error message. I want to determine whether the error was SQLError, and execute some code depending on this.
Determine by error message is bad way cause content of `e.message` can be different

Answer (score 0):

I found a way in check "`e.constructor.name`" attribute. In case of SQLError it equals to `"SQLError"`

```
mydb.pQuery()    // method returns Promise. It can throw SQLError by SQLite
    .catch(function(e){
        if(e.constructor.name==='SQLError'){
            // code
        }
    })
```